# Assigning a category/group based on date in R

Tags: r, date

I am quite new to R.
I have a dataset (AllData) with hatching date for birds from many years. I added a column for the day ("%d/%m") of hatching (independent of year), and want to change all dates (or potentially add new column) within certain interval (~14 days) to be either "Early", "Middle" or "Late".

Here is what I tried to do:

AllData$HatchingDay[AllData$HatchingDay <= "01/06"  & AllData$HatchingDay >= "15/06"] <- "Early"
AllData$HatchingDay[AllData$HatchingDay <= "16/06"  & AllData$HatchingDay >= "30/06"] <- "Middle"
AllData$HatchingDay[AllData$HatchingDay <= "01/07"  & AllData$HatchingDay >= "15/07"] <- "Late"

The code runs fine, but nothing happens in the column.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are using `<=` and `>=` on strings, what will work but with a format of `%d/%m` it will not result in what you expect. Maybe flip month and day: `%m%d`.

Answer (score 0):

Often, I have trouble in working with dates formatted as an actual date variable. Therefore, I prefer to convert them into a numeric variable. For this, be careful on the date system used by your computer. In my example below, 1st of June 2022 becomes 44713.
Maybe not elegant, but here is my suggestion:

```
AllData %>%
      mutate_at(vars(HatchingDay), as.numeric) %>% #convert to numeric
      mutate(timeinterval = case_when( #new variable
      HatchingDay >= 44713 & settimana <= 44727 ~ "early", #define condition for factor levels
      HatchingDay >= 44728 & HatchingDay <= 44742 ~ "middle",
      HatchingDay >= 44743 & HatchingDay <= 44757 ~ "late",
      TRUE ~ "error")) #display error if a value is not assigned to one of the previous groups
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Since I would have to to this for all of my 15 years of data, I tried using your code without changing it to numeric, and it worked! It was similiar to what I had already tried, but this was the code that ended up working:                     
AllData<-AllData %>%
  mutate(Hatching_time = case_when( #new variable
    Hatching_day >= 15/06 & Hatching_day <= 24/06  ~ "early", #define condition for factor levels
    Hatching_day >= 25/06 & Hatching_day <= 04/07  ~ "middle",
    Hatching_day >= 05/07 & Hatching_day <= 14/07 ~ "late",
    TRUE ~ "NA"))

Comment: Never mind...the code only recognize the day (%d) and gives it a group based on that, not the month